# how to create a (2) 2d arrays that is 6 by 3 and can hold strings and ints

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Im trying to create a (2)2d arrays with strings and ints so that ill be able to sort them out later on in the code.  This is my code so far and i keep getting errors when trying to compile and im not sure what to do:

```
public class SchoolBus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[][] students = new Student[6][3];
        students[0][0] = "Mabel";
        students[0][1] = new int[1];
        students[0][2] = new Integer(2);
        students[1][0] = "Dipper";
        students[1][1] = new Integer(1);
        students[1][2] = new Integer(4);
        students[2][0] = "Sam";
        students[2][1] = new Integer(1);
        students[2][2] = new Integer(7);
        students[3][0] = "Ian";
        students[3][1] = new Integer(2);
        students[3][2] = new Integer(3);
        students[4][0] = "Jordan";
        students[4][1] = new Integer(2);
        students[4][2] = new Integer(6);
        students[5][0] = "Steven";
        students[5][1] = new Integer(2);
        students[5][2] = new Integer(9);
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it _have_ to be an array? There are better data structures for this. Would you like us to answer the question "How should I best store collections of related integers and strings?"?

Comment: Also, it looks like you have defined a class `Student` somewhere. It would be helpful to see that so that we can create a better answer for you.

Comment: Your array type is `Student`,  so that is what it will hold.

Comment: You're also trying to print a variable that does not exist; student. Maybe you forgot the 's' at the end? Although java.util.Arrays have methods to print String-representations of arrays, otherwise you won't see its content, only some internal array identifier.

Comment: I don't think the code present is close to what's actually wanted. The end product probably won't have an arrays (it might have a `Set` of `Student`s). When we see what's actually required, we can suggest answers that will get OP to his desired state as fast as possible.

Comment: @PaulHicks what other data structure would you recommend?  Im quite new to java as you may or may not see would it help if i posted the question that this is related to?  Its homework for trying to get into a robotics team and i know its against the rules on this website im pretty sure but if possible could you help me with it?  Or if anything point me in the right direction.

Comment: First and most obvious would be the `Student` class, for holding the name and two ints in named properties. I'd probably use a `Set` for holding multiple students. A `List` is also valid but since students are probably unique, a `Set` is more likely to capture the correct semantics.

Answer (score 0):

For other data structures, consider using for example a Collection such as a List. Collections allow you to sort easily.

Here's one example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class SchoolBus {
    private SchoolBus() {

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        students.add(new Student("Mabel", 1, 2));
        students.add(new Student("Dipper", 1, 4));
        students.add(new Student("Sam", 1, 7));
        students.add(new Student("Ian", 2, 3));
        students.add(new Student("Jordan", 2, 6));
        students.add(new Student("Steven", 2, 9));

        System.out.println(students);

        Collections.sort(students, SchoolBus::compare);

        System.out.println(students);
    }

    public static int compare(final Student a, final Student b) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }

    private static final class Student {
        private final int a;
        private final int b;
        private final String name;

        public Student(final String name, final int a, final int b) {
            this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name, "name == null");
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public int getA() {
            return this.a;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return this.b;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Student: [Name=%s], [A=%s], [B=%s]", this.name, Integer.toString(this.a), Integer.toString(this.b));
        }
    }
}
```